# sys.stdin as a file to iterate over

Tags: python

I am writing a script that searches a regex in a file (input is file path), or in stdin in case a '-' was entered instead of a file path.

I did some debugging and I think the problem is on "for i, line in enumerate(file):" because it doesn't go inside there.

When I do this in Python 3.x it works, but in python 2.7 it just doesn't go inside that loop

Here is some part of the script

```
def init_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The script searches one or \
                                     more named input files for lines \
                                     containing a match to a regular \
                                     expression pattern.")
    parser.add_argument('regex', help='the regular expression.')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-',
                        help='the name of the file(s) to search.')

    return parser


args = init_parser().parse_args()
for file in args.infile:
    if args.infile == '-':
        file = sys.stdin
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        substrings = re.finditer(args.regex, line)
        if substrings:
            for substring in substrings:
                    print_line(file.name, i + 1, line[:-1])
```

Comment: What is `args.infile` supposed to be? It's hard to imagine a situation where both `for file in args.infile` and `if args.infile == '-'` make sense.

Comment: `args.infile` is supposed to be a file path. in case the it's not provide, the script should search in stdin.

Comment: `args.infile` is never going to be a file path. It's going to be a sequence of file objects.

Comment: How are you feeding data to stdin? Through a pipe? Typing it into the terminal by hand?

Comment: Typing it into the terminal by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 uses a different buffering scheme than Python 3 for iterating over files. It wants to either fill the buffer or see the end of the file before it starts the first iteration. You're typing input into stdin by hand, and you haven't either typed enough to fill the buffer or signaled end-of-file, so you never reach the first iteration.

To iterate over a file without this buffering, you can use two-argument [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter). This works in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
    ...
```

Also, you have (at least) two other bugs. First, the following two lines aren't doing what you think they are:

```
if args.infile == '-':
    file = sys.stdin
```

`args.infile` is a sequence of file objects, not a string. You don't notice the bug because `argparse.FileType` is actually handling `-` for you.

There's a second bug, that the first bug happens to be hiding. The default value of `infile`:

```
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-',
                    help='the name of the file(s) to search.')
```

should be `[sys.stdin]`, not `'-'`. The default value doesn't go through `type` handling or automatically get wrapped in a list, so you have to do that yourself. Otherwise, this loop:

```
for file in args.infile:
```

ends up iterating over the characters of `'-'` instead of iterating over files.

To fix these bugs, change the default for `infile` to `[sys.stdin]`, and remove the `if args.infile == '-':` handling.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it but I get an error message `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'" `

Comment: @user2956817: That might be due to a second bug I forgot to address in the first version of the answer. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you! last question- in your solution you put out the "i" variable.. how can I add it back properly?

Comment: @user2956817: `for i, line in enumerate(iter(file.readline, ''))`